# What is the correct way to calculate a selling price from margin and a cost?

Tags: pricing

There seems to be two formula to calculate a selling price.

The first formula that I came upon would be

```
Cost * (1+Margin) = Selling price
Example : 10 * (1+0.25) = 12.5
```

However, a lot of people uses the following :

```
Cost / (1 - Margin) = Selling price
Example : 10 / (1-0.25) = 13.33...
```

This gives a very different number.

As far as I know, the margin and selling prices can be anything you want for most products.

Also note that the second formula fails if you have a margin of more dans 100%.

My question is why is the second formula the most popular ? Is it only a gimmick to get a bigger price?

Am I missing something subtle at work here ?

Also, what should I do if the wanted margin is more than 100% ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "**margin**" is a *portion of the selling price*. It is defined as

$$\text {margin} \equiv \frac {P-C}{P}$$

From the above *definition*, we see that the margin cannot exceed $100\%$.

If one has the cost and he wants to calculate the price in order to have a specific margin, one must calculate

$$P(\text {margin}^*) = \frac {C}{1-\text {margin}^*}$$

The first formula written in the question is wrong, because it uses "margin", but it would become correct if instead one used the concept of "markup".

The "**markup**" is defined as the percentage increase of cost in order to determine the selling price:

$$\text {markup} \equiv \frac {P-C}{C}$$

It is easy to obtain that the relation between them is

$$\text {margin} = \frac {\text {markup}}{1+\text {markup}}$$